# How to set Texture2D layer order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a timer that I draw to the screen as a Texture2D rendered atop a Rect.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to let other elements on the screen appear over or under it.  Currently, it's drawn on top of absolutely everything but I need the menu to appear over it.

Hopefully this is not missing any relevant info.  I had to delete a ton of code that involves the timer filling and other elements of the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float timerWidth; // X coordinate for all timers' placement.
    public float timerHeight; // Y coordinate for timer's placement.
    Rect timeBarRect; // The bar coordinates.
    Rect blankBarRect; // The blank bar coordinates.
    Texture2D timeTexture; // Color of bar when it is filling.
    Texture2D blankBarTexture; // Bar that has yet to be filled.

    void Start (){

        timerHeight = 1.528f;
        timerWidth = 4.54f;

        cam = (GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>()) as Camera;

        blankBarRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width / 3, Screen.height / 50);
        timeBarRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width / 3, Screen.height / 50);         

        timeTexture = new Texture2D (1, 1);
        timeTexture.SetPixel(0,0, Color.green);
        timeTexture.Apply();

        blankBarTexture = new Texture2D (1, 1);
        blankBarTexture.SetPixel(0,0, Color.black);
        blankBarTexture.Apply();
    }

    void Update ()
    {

        timeBarRect.x = cam.pixelWidth / timerWidth;
        timeBarRect.y = cam.pixelHeight / timerHeight;

        blankBarRect.x = cam.pixelWidth / timerWidth;
        blankBarRect.y = cam.pixelHeight / timerHeight;
    }

    void OnGUI(){ 

        blankBarRect.width = (Screen.width * .1f); 
        GUI.DrawTexture (blankBarRect, blankBarTexture);

        timeBarRect.width = ((Screen.width * .1f)); 
        GUI.DrawTexture (timeBarRect, timeTexture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you use Unity 5 with the new UI (that came in 4.6) the draw order becomes very simple: UI objects in your scene hierarchy will render "top to bottom" (if they are siblings = have the same parent) and "parent to child" otherwise

Comment: @JinJi The textures I am talking about are not attached to any GameObject.  I tried dragging the object that has the code that creates them, but it didn't matter where I dragged it in the scene hierarchy; they remained on top of everything

Comment: yes, i saw that - you are using OnGUI and GUI.DrawTexture - which is part of the old / legacy / obsolete UI (before 4.6) - that is why i suggested using the new UI instead - you will have less problems

Comment: @JinJi Oh I misunderstood.  I am not sure how to go about that.  Can you give me an example of what to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete this:

```
void OnGUI(){ 
    blankBarRect.width = (Screen.width * .1f); 
    GUI.DrawTexture (blankBarRect, blankBarTexture);

    timeBarRect.width = ((Screen.width * .1f)); 
    GUI.DrawTexture (timeBarRect, timeTexture);
}
```

and make a RawImage GameObject in your scene hierarchy under Canvas

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html

you can then use `FindWithTag()` and `GetComponent<RawImage>()` to get the component and set its Texture property with your own texture

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage.html